# ExactTarget/FuelSDK-CSharp implementing objects not included in the SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, fuel-sdk

There are examples for using objects that are included in the SDK (eg. ET_List). How would I go about using an object that is not implemented, like AccountUser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_a_new_user_to_an_existing_account/) example should help you out. If you need to use an existing user, you should do a retrieve operation rather than a create, rest of the flow remains the same.

Comment: That example uses an API User for credentials. My understanding was using the SDK now you only need the Client ID and Client Secret to get a token and that's what you use for authentication. It doesn't make sense to have to have 2 authentication methods with the SDK does it?

Comment: Both authentication methods exist in the SDK because there are some SFMC Objects you can only use REST to interact with (e.g. Journey Builder) and vise-versa.